# Jasper Report Rows layout, Avery A7654 format

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to print jasper reports on Avery L7654 (40 Labels per sheet) Label sheet. I have attached my present configuration. With this configuration I am getting 4*12 per sheet. But am looking for 4*10 (40 labels per sheet). Please suggest how do to configure the report. 
http://uk.onlinelabels.com/Templates/EU30018-template-microsoft-word.htm

[image]

Comment: It seems to be like you just need to set correct height of your detail band. (hench now you are getting 12, increase it to just get 10)....

Comment: you are exactly right

Comment: Thanks, I suggest you post the correct answer and accept it...

Comment: I exactly do not know how much height I need to set. at same time the dimensions should also adjust to Avery L7654 dimensions (EU30018 - 45.7mm x 25.5mm Labels).

Comment: I have posted an answer on how you can  convert your mm to pixels in jasper report, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows you get are determined by the **detail band**.

If you need a row height **25.5 mm** this would give us about **72 pixels**.

```
pixels = (mm * dpi) / 25.4; //The DPI in jasper report is 72
```

So the definition of the detail band should be:

```
<detail>
    <band height="72">
     ... your text fields ...
    </band>
</detail>
```